# python file name change

Tags: python, filenames

I am trying to change file names like below:
the 000000 are the same number.

```
000000_ABC.png      --->000000+1_ABC.png
000000_DEF.png      --->000000+2_DEF.png
000000_GHI.png      --->000000+3_GHI.png
000000_JKL.png      --->000000+4_JKL.png
```

In order to do so, I wrote code like below.

```
img_files = os.listdir(PATH_TO_PNG_FILES)
for img_file, i in zip(img_files, range(len(img_files))):
    new_img_file = img_file.replace("_", "+"+str(i)+"_")
    os.rename(path + img_file, path + new_img_file)
```

There are more than just four files and more of similar lines.
The problem is that immediately after running pycharm, it successfully produces the desired results, but after I run another page related to the result directories, the results continue to be changed like below even after the process finished. I do not understand why.

```
000000+1+1_ABC.png
000000+2+2_DEF.png
000000+3+3_GHI.png
000000+4+4_JKL.png

or 

otherwise "+unexpected number"
```

Comment: Not related to your actual question, but you can use the built-in function `enumerate()` to replace your `zip(range(...`

Comment: Looks like you ran this bit of code more than once. `but after I run another page` - can you expand on that in your question? When you *ran another page* was this code also run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the other directory may already contain file in the format of "000000+1_ABC.png" and your script is changing _ to "+1_" resulting in "000000+1+1_ABC.png". To solve this you can add a if statement to check it should not contain "+" symbol.

```
img_files = os.listdir(path inside of which the png files are saved)
for img_file, i in zip(img_files, range(len(img_files))):
    if not ("+" in img_file):
        new_img_file = img_file.replace("_", "+"+str(i)+"_")
        os.rename(path + img_file, path + new_img_file)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and naive way would be to add a verification to check whether there is a '+' in the filename. If you have other files which may contain a +, you may have to check for a stricter pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I made a YouTube video https://youtu.be/K9jhAPZLZLc  on how to rename multiple files like the one you have assuming all your files are in the same directory.

To answer your question. assuming all image files are in the same folder.

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\rename_images\\images\\' # path to your images
files = os.listdir(path)

for count, filename in enumerate(files):
    # Get the file extension
    file, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)

    # check if the current file is a folder or not
    full_path = f'{path}{filename}'

    if os.path.isdir(full_path):
        print('This is a directory')
    elif os.path.isfile(full_path):
        print('This is a normal file')
        # Rename
        if  not '+' in file:
            try:
                file_split = file.split('_')
                zeros = file_split[0]
                alpha = file_split[-1]
                current_file_name = os.path.join(path, filename)
                new_file_name = os.path.join(path, ''.join([f'{zeros}+{count}_{alpha}', file_extension]))

                os.rename(current_file_name, new_file_name)
            except:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    else:
        print('This is a special file')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the problem comes from modifying the name insted of overwriting.

```
import os
DIR_PATH = 'files'

def rename_files(dir_name):
    img_files = os.listdir(dir_name)
    for i in range(len(img_files)):
        file_name = img_files[i].split('_')[-1]
        file_name = '000000+{0}_{1}'.format(i, file_name)
        os.rename(
            os.path.join(dir_name, img_files[i]),
            os.path.join(dir_name, file_name)
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rename_files(DIR_PATH)
```